# Perform calculation for varchar data type column

Tags: sql, database

I have a inventory quantity column in database and its data type is varchar. When workers take out the product from store, the inventory quantity should be deducted. And I am having some problem when writing Sql statement:

```
public bool updateInventoryQty(string productID, int prodQty)
    {
        bool result = false;
        result = Conversion.intToBool(FoodBankDB.executeNonQuery(
            "UPDATE dbo.products SET inventoryQuantity = inventoryQuantity - prodQty WHERE id = '" + productID + "'"
            ));

        return result;
    }
```

I take in the amount taken out as parameter. Since the inventoryQuantity is varchar so I think it could not perform any calculation. So am I supposed to change it to:

```
"UPDATE dbo.products SET Convert(INT, inventoryQuantity) = inventoryQuantity - prodQty WHERE id = '" + productID + "'"
```

Am I doing in the correct way? Thanks in advance.

Comment: use parameterised queries

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type) - you should always use the most appropriate data type - that's what they're there for, after all! And a `quantity` by definition is a **numerical** value - so it should be stored as such - definitely **NOT** as a `varchar` !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be converting the other side of the assignment:

```
"UPDATE dbo.products 
SET inventoryQuantity = CAST((CAST(inventoryQuantity AS INT) - prodQty) AS VARCHAR(20)) WHERE id = '" + productID + "'"
```

Also, do not concatenate your queries, use parameters. You are vulnerable to SQL injection now.

Comment: My prodQty is a variable. When I run it, it show me an error message "Invalid column name prodQty".

Comment: So shouldn't you use `@prodQty`?